# pgfplots — Align two separate plots by x-axes and align captions

Tags: pgfplots, alignment

Here's a concrete example that illustrates the problem

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\pgfplotsset{disabledatascaling}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    
    \rule{1pt}{157pt} % dirty hack

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=2,
    unit vector ratio=1 1,
    ]
    \pgfplotsextra{\xdef\pUnit{\pgfplotsunitylength}}
    
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x, x^2);
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \rule{1pt}{50pt} % dirty hack
    
    \caption{}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[x=\pUnit,y=\pUnit,
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=5,
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1
    ]
    
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x/2, x^3);
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, currently I managed to get the desired alignment via abusing `\rule`, but it requires trials and errors so that it takes dozens of compilation iteration to eyeball the alignemnt.

*Kept rule's width on purpose to make it visible*

---

How to automate this process and get the precise alignment of both: two tikzpictures by x-axis, but also captions so that they appear at the same height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aligns the tikzpictures using `[baseline=(...)]`, and aligns the captions by using a separate row.  I used `\makebox` because the tikzpictures weren't fitting into the space given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]% friends don't let friends use H
\pgfplotsset{disabledatascaling}

\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(origin)]
    \begin{axis}[unit vector ratio=1 1,
    axis lines = center,
    %domain=(-2:1),
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=2,
    ]
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x, x^2);
    \pgfplotsextra{\xdef\pUnit{\pgfplotsunitylength}}
    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0);% Note additions
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
\makebox[0.5\linewidth]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(origin)]
    \begin{axis}[x={\pUnit}, y={\pUnit},
    axis lines = center,
    %domain=(-3:2),
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=5,
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1
    ]
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x/2, x^3);
    
    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs: 0,0);% Note additions
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \caption{}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really neat approach, thanks!

Comment: Btw, it doesn't fit with `minipage` only because you removed crucial `unit vector ratio=1 1` option for me. If you keep it, everything works even with `minipage` env instead of `\makebox`. Also, if you're using new versions of `pgfplots`, adding `axis cs:` can be omitted.

Comment: I just **like** using `axis cs:`.  It removes any uncertainty.  (Sorry about the `unit vector`; I was removing everything at the time.)

Comment: Figured out an improvement: `baseline=(current axis.origin)` — with that you don't need to additionally create `\coordinate` inside each of axes.

Answer (score 0):

This answer only a sum up of [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo)'s answers with some improvements that make it even easier. But all credits go to his answer.

The key here is to set a baseline for each of the tikzpictures at the origin `(0,0)`. This can be done via prefedined node: `(current axis.origin)`. Now you can even give up outer wrapper for tikzpictures, but still use `minipage` only for creating captions.

So that we end up with a really simple structure

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.origin)]
    ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \quad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.origin)]
    ...
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\caption{}\end{minipage}
    \quad
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\caption{}\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float} % only for H firgure placement

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\pgfplotsset{disabledatascaling}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.origin)]
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-2,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=2,
    unit vector ratio=1 1,
    ]
    \pgfplotsextra{\xdef\pUnit{\pgfplotsunitylength}}
    
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x, x^2);
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current axis.origin)]
    \begin{axis}[x=\pUnit,y=\pUnit,
    axis lines = center,
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=-2,
    ymax=5,
    xtick distance=1,
    ytick distance=1
    ]
    
    \addplot[blue,samples=100] (x/2, x^3);
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\caption{}\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}\caption{}\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```